# How to perform maven release plugin with Google Cloud build

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, google-cloud-build

I try to use google cloud build to build a spring boot application hosted on Github. I have a specific trigger to perform a maven release of my project.

But I don't find how to configure git, Maven, and cloud-build.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the maven release plugin, but hopefully this will be useful:

- configuring cloud build to github

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds

- configuring maven

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/mvn/examples/spring_boot

- possible config file

```
steps:
# run unit tests
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['test']
# prepare release
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['release:prepare']
# perform release
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/mvn'
  args: ['release:perform']
```